# How to normalize colormap of a geopandas plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am trying to draw a traffic flow map.

The code I used is as below:

```
def map_draw(transport_gdf, map_path=map_path):

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 16), facecolor=(0.37, 0.39, 0.41))
plt.axis("off")
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.xlim((110, 125))
plt.ylim((32, 42))

CHN_adm = CHN_map(map_path)
CHN_adm.plot(ax=ax, color="black", edgecolor=(0.37, 0.39, 0.41), linewidth=2.5)

transport_gdf.plot(
    column=np.log(transport_gdf.iloc[:, -1]),
    ax=ax,
    cmap="autumn",
    linewidth=transport_gdf.iloc[:, -1] / 100000,
)
```

where `transport_gdf` is a GeoDataFrame object like this.
[image]

And what I got is like this:
[image]

Here, I want to normalize the colormap I have applied. Is there any way I can do this?

I went through Stackoverflow and only found an answer for a scatter plot, which does not apply to my situation.

Comment: Try setting the option `column='0'` in `transport_gdf.plot()`, assuming `'0'` is the column name that its values are used with `cmap='autumn'`.

Comment: `@swatchai`, Thank u for your comment. I think here I already used column `'0'` in plotting, as in  `column=np.log(transport_gdf.iloc[:, -1])`, where `.iloc[:, -1])` is the column `0`.  I rethink my problem here. i think the true question is how to set a fixed max and min value for the colormap, so that the colormap would reflect the change of the value in column `'0'`